# Modular Inverse with C# not working as expected

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate the modular Inverse. This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work.

```
while (priv != 1)
{
    priv = ((x * other) % modulo);
    x++;
    textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + "Trying: " + priv.ToString() + " ..."+"\n";
    if (priv == 1)
    {
        textBox3.Text = (" IS: " + priv.ToString() +" !");
    }
}
```

Sometimes this outputs `1`, or nothing.

I'm attempting the modular inverse `(x) of [x*781]%2828 = 1`

Comment: A modular inverse exists for this pair of numbers, since `GCD(781, 2828)==1

Comment: Not strictly an answer to your question, but something which you might not know.

It looks like you are trying to us textBox3.Text as some form of status indication? This is a problem as it will not be changed onscreen until the method completes.

If you want to get some notifications for progress you'd be far better off using Debug.WriteLine() to put some information into the Output window of VS. At least until you figure things out. 

That or look up UI multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

It outputs 1 or nothing because the output code is wrapped in a `priv == 1` check...

You probably want this change to your code (unsure if the computation is correct because it's not the cause of the issue you're describing):

```
while (priv != 1)
{
    priv = ((x * other) % modulo);
    x++;
    textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + "Trying: " + priv.ToString() + " ..."+"\n";
    if (priv == 1)
    {
        break;  // end the loop
    }
}

textBox3.Text = (" IS: " + priv.ToString() +" !");
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'd hate to ruin your homework for you. Here's a wikipedia article about various algorithms to calculate what you need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse